# Construct deep struct is not working

Tags: dictionary, go, struct, hashmap, yaml

i’ve struct which responsible to parse data from yaml file
While this struct is working sometimes I got some newly fields which I need to parse

**This is working**

```
  - name: test1
    type: type
    path: path
```

**This is not**

```
 - name: test1
    type: type
    path: path
    build-parameters:
       maven-opts:
          defines:
              skipTests: true
```

**This is the struct**

```
type Modules struct {
    Name string
    Type string
    Path string
    Parameters Parameters `yaml:"build-parameters,omitempty"`
}
```

And the parameters is type of:

```
type Parameters map[string]string
```

How I should construct my struct to accept this build-parameters entries also?

This is the library I use

https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your struct does not match the data structure. If `Parameters` is a `map[string]string`, it accepts key-value pairs where the key and value are both `string`. In your data, `build-parameters` contains an object, which contains an object, which contains a key-value pair.

You could either redefine `Parameters` to be `map[string]interface{}` and use type assertions, or you can define the entire structure, e.g.:

```
type Parameters struct {
    MavenOpts struct {
        Defines map[string]string
    } `yaml:"maven-opts"`
}
```

If you use the empty interface, you'll have to use type assertions, which can get pretty cumbersome. For example:

```
if opts, ok := module.Parameters["maven-opts"].(map[string]interface{}); ok {
    if defines,ok := opts["defines"].(map[string]interface{}); ok {
        if skipTests,ok := defines["skipTests"].(bool); ok {
            // skipTests is the bool value from the yaml
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, 1+ can you please also provide the e.g. with the interface (`map[string]interface{}`)and how I should get the data from it as answer, now its maven opts and build parameters but it can be any values with this structure....`MavenOpts` on your example is hardcode and it can be any value...

Comment: Type assertions are well-documented [in the tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) and [in the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

Comment: my biggest lack of knowlage here that if I use the `map[string]interface{}`, how should I access to find the value e.g. for `skipTests` ...

Comment: Thanks but here its a deep structure ...which is a bit diffrent and a bit complicated

Comment: It's not at all different. You do the exact same type assertion you find in the documentation at each level of nesting.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adrian